# Zabbix vfs.fs.size gives wrong result when filesystem is not mounted

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am using an item `vfs.fs.size[/bakcrypt,free]` (generated by autodiscovery) to monitor diskspace on an encrypted file system (and of course others). The encrypted filesystem in **not auto mounted** immediately at system startup because a **passphrase has to be entered manually**.

The problem is, that while my `/bakcrypt` is not (yet) mounted `vfs.fs.size[/bakcrypt,free]` gives the size of the "parent" filesystem (`/`) which is wrong. This leads to wrong triggers/alarms and jumps in the disk space graph.

Is there any way to prevent vfs.fs.size from giving a result if the named filesystem is not currently mounted?

Or is there a means of "conitional expression"? Something like `whenmounted(/bakcrypt,vfs.fs.size[/bakcrypt,free])`.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a check, something like

```
vfs.file.regmatch[/proc/mounts,^\S+ /bakcrypt .*]
```

and then customize your original trigger alert for the disk space with a condition, if the regmatch = 1 and diskspace is low, then alert.

Comment: It won't solve your grah issue tho.. I'll make another answer if I find something out to resolve this, I need to get at the office to make some tests, I'm in the subway atm.

Comment: Thank you very much, looks good, nice idea - I'll try this and give feedback. As you also noticed - this won't solve the graph-jumps-problem. I'd be happy to get a solution for this, too.

Comment: I've just tried this idea and the trigger works as expected using this expression: `{martiniesrv:vfs.fs.size[/bakcrypt,free].last(0)}<20G and {martiniesrv:vfs.file.regmatch[/proc/mounts,^\S+ /bakcrypt .*].last(0)}>0`.

In addition to this I've added a trigger to just check if /bakcrypt is mounted: `{martiniesrv:vfs.file.regmatch[/proc/mounts,^\S+ /bakcrypt .*].last(0)}=0`.

Thank you again for this help. I'd appreciate getting any idea for the graphing problem.

Comment: I still experienced a problem with my diskspace trigger: The 2 items in the trigger expression are not updated at the same time. So it can happen that the mount-check still results in "true" but the size-checks already has the low value because /bakcrypt is not mounted. My solution is the following expression: `{martiniesrv:vfs.fs.size[/bakcrypt,free].max(#2)}<20G and {martiniesrv:vfs.file.regmatch[/proc/mounts,^\S+ /bakcrypt .*].last()}>0`

Comment: Glad I was able to help you for one part of your problem. I did some tests on my side, still didn't find a workaround for this graph issue, I'm not sure there's one.. I'll ask on the Zabbix forum to see if someone has an idea for this.

Comment: Now I read something about calculated items. Do you have an idea how to build an appropriate expression for an item to get a "clean" disk space graph?